# Анимация знака радиационной безопасности

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, svg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне необходимо анимировать знак радиационной безопасности. 
Анимация должна быть реализована с помощью прорисовки контуров знака с последующим заполнением цветом.

Для анимации я перерисовал картинку знака в формате *.png  в формат *.svg.

Ниже код:

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="120.00000mm" id="svg1329" width="120.00000mm" version="1.1">
  <circle cx="60mm" cy="60mm" r="60mm" fill="#F8F73F" stroke="black" />
  <g id="layer1" transform="translate(0,-12)">
    <g id="BigCircle" transform="matrix(1.199956,0,0,1.19999,-233.4664,-55.73655) translate(10.5 10.5)">
      <path  d="m395.16131 232.61269a67.2615 44.841002 0 1 1-134.523 0 67.2615 44.841002 0 1 1 134.523 0z" id="path2277"  fill="none"/>
     
      <path id="smallCircle" fill="black" stroke="black"  d="m395.16131 232.61269a67.2615 44.841002 0 1 1-134.523 0 67.2615 44.841002 0 1 1 134.523 0z"  transform="matrix(0.526796,0,0,0.790194,199.0044,49.80387)" />
     
  <path id="sector"   d="m283.25 80.3125c-52.94223 30.64719-88.6875 87.77938-88.6875 153.3125l124.03125 0c0-19.6576 10.71419-36.80504 26.59375-46L283.25 80.3125Zm177 0-61.9375 107.3125c15.86678 9.19825 26.5625 26.35197 26.5625 46l124.03125 0c0-65.52623-35.72322-122.66294-88.65625-153.3125zm-61.96875 199.28125c-7.82037 4.52833-16.85027 7.15625-26.53125 7.15625-9.67517 0-18.74531-2.60171-26.5625-7.125L283.25 386.90625c26.06363 15.08771 56.23784 23.875 88.5 23.875 32.25951 0 62.40658-8.7896 88.46875-23.875l-61.9375-107.3125z"  fill="black" stroke="black"/>
      
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

*Для реализации анимации допустимы:  анимации css3, smil svg, Javascript*

Очень хотелось бы получить несколько ответов, с разнообразными техниками выполнения.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Вариант с `<animate/>`

**Первый шаг:**

Сначала узнаем длину `stroke`:

```
<script>
 function TotalLength(){
   var path = document.querySelector('#sector');
   var len = Math.round(path.getTotalLength() );
   alert("Длина пути - " + len);
};
</script>
```

После поместим в каждый патч `stroke-dashoffset` & `stroke-dasharray`

**Второй шаг:**

Далее делаем сам `<animate/>` внутри `<path id="sector">` & `<path id="BigCircle">`:

```
<animate id="strokeTap" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s" values="1467;0" dur="3s" fill="freeze" />
```

Анимация закрашивания:
**P.S.** Будет срабатывать только тогда, когда первая анимация закончится, `begin="strokeTap.end"`

```
<animate id="fillTap" attributeName="fill" values="#F8F73F; #000" begin="strokeTap.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
```

**Третий шаг:**

Также поместим `<animate/>` в `<circle>`:

```
<animate id="strokeTap" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s" values="1430;0" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
<animate id="fill" attributeName="fill" values="#fff; #F8F73F" begin="strokeTap.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" /></circle>
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="120.00000mm" id="svg1329" width="120.00000mm" version="1.1">
      <circle cx="60mm" cy="60mm" r="60mm" stroke="black" stroke-dashoffset="1430" stroke-dasharray="1430" fill="none">
       <animate id="strokeTap" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s" values="1430;0" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
      <animate id="fill" attributeName="fill" values="#fff; #F8F73F" begin="strokeTap.end" dur="2s" fill="freeze" /></circle>
      <g id="layer1" transform="translate(0,-12)">
        <g id="BigCircle" transform="matrix(1.199956,0,0,1.19999,-233.4664,-55.73655) translate(10.5 10.5)">
          <path id="smallCircle" fill="none" stroke-dashoffset="360" stroke-dasharray="360" stroke="black" d="m395.16131 232.61269a67.2615 44.841002 0 1 1-134.523 0 67.2615 44.841002 0 1 1 134.523 0z"
            transform="matrix(0.526796,0,0,0.790194,199.0044,49.80387)">
            <animate id="strokeTap" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s" values="360;0" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
            <animate id="fillCircle" attributeName="fill" values="#fff;#000" begin="strokeTap.end" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
          </path>
          <path id="sector" fill="none" stroke-dashoffset="1467" stroke-dasharray="1467" d="m283.25 80.3125c-52.94223 30.64719-88.6875 87.77938-88.6875 153.3125l124.03125 0c0-19.6576 10.71419-36.80504 26.59375-46L283.25 80.3125Zm177 0-61.9375 107.3125c15.86678 9.19825 26.5625 26.35197 26.5625 46l124.03125 0c0-65.52623-35.72322-122.66294-88.65625-153.3125zm-61.96875 199.28125c-7.82037 4.52833-16.85027 7.15625-26.53125 7.15625-9.67517 0-18.74531-2.60171-26.5625-7.125L283.25 386.90625c26.06363 15.08771 56.23784 23.875 88.5 23.875 32.25951 0 62.40658-8.7896 88.46875-23.875l-61.9375-107.3125z"
            stroke="black">
            <animate id="strokeTap" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s" values="1467;0" dur="6s" fill="freeze" />
            <animate id="fillTap" attributeName="fill" values="#fff; #000" begin="strokeTap.end" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
          </path>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Хорошо, только на мой взгляд, было бы эффективнее, если бы  прорисовка контуров заканчивалась в один момент,  а потом  заливка тоже...

Comment: @Air, наглядный пример, да, не спорю

Comment: @St1myL отлично, сейчас намного лучше смотрится, чем в первых вариантах

Answer (score 3):

Вариант на `CSS`:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#mainCircle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1424;
  stroke-dasharray: 1424;
  animation: main-circle 2s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.05, 0.795, 0.035) forwards;
}

#sector {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1467;
  stroke-dasharray: 1467;
  animation: stroke 4s cubic-bezier(0.95, 0.05, 0.795, 0.035) forwards;
}

#smallCircle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke-dashoffset: 356;
  stroke-dasharray: 356;
  animation: stroke-small 4s cubic-bezier(0.95, 0.05, 0.795, 0.035) forwards;
}

@keyframes main-circle {
  to {
    fill: #F8F73F;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes stroke {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1467;
  }
  to {
    fill: black;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes stroke-small {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 356;
  }
  to {
    fill: black;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="120.00000mm" id="svg1329" width="120.00000mm" version="1.1">
      <circle id="mainCircle" cx="60mm" cy="60mm" r="60mm"/>
      <g id="layer1" transform="translate(0,-12)">
        <g id="BigCircle" transform="matrix(1.199956,0,0,1.19999,-233.4664,-55.73655) translate(10.5 10.5)">
          <path id="smallCircle" stroke="black" d="m395.16131 232.61269a67.2615 44.841002 0 1 1-134.523 0 67.2615 44.841002 0 1 1 134.523 0z"
            transform="matrix(0.526796,0,0,0.790194,199.0044,49.80387)">
          </path>
          <path id="sector" d="m283.25 80.3125c-52.94223 30.64719-88.6875 87.77938-88.6875 153.3125l124.03125 0c0-19.6576 10.71419-36.80504 26.59375-46L283.25 80.3125Zm177 0-61.9375 107.3125c15.86678 9.19825 26.5625 26.35197 26.5625 46l124.03125 0c0-65.52623-35.72322-122.66294-88.65625-153.3125zm-61.96875 199.28125c-7.82037 4.52833-16.85027 7.15625-26.53125 7.15625-9.67517 0-18.74531-2.60171-26.5625-7.125L283.25 386.90625c26.06363 15.08771 56.23784 23.875 88.5 23.875 32.25951 0 62.40658-8.7896 88.46875-23.875l-61.9375-107.3125z"
            stroke="black">
          </path>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```