# Как нарисовать и аниммировать svg линии?

Tags: css, svg

Как в SVG нарисовать и анимировать 2 линии, чтобы сначала "нарисовалась" одна прямая, затем вторая?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сделать `path`, найти его длину и поместить значение в `stroke-dashoffset` , после анимировать с N до нуля. Такие вопросы уже были на ruSO. Скину, если найду.

Comment: оО круто вы там нарисовали,спасибо, попробую понять

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Анимация знака радиационной безопасности](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/790232/%d0%90%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8)